# Can't remove dataup adware

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus-removal

Last night I got the dataup adware on my PC, I've done virus and malware removal before, but this one won't go away and is proving to be quite stubborn. I've used Malwarebytes, HitmanPro, and Norton Security Suite on it and none of them view it as a threat. I've even tried removing it from scheduled tasks, but it manages to put it's self back in there on each reboot afterwords. I have also used Unlocker to try and either delete or rename the executable upon system reboot, but that also doesn't work. I'm not too worried as most articles and documentation on the program say it's basically a nuisance more than anything else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a virus, nuke the machine and restore from back up...

Comment: Damn, I was hoping to avoid that... But it is the safest thing to do I suppose.